# NiFi - Not Seeing user/password in nifi-app.log

Tags: apache-nifi

In Windows, I've downloaded, installed, and started NiFi 1.16.3.

However when it asks me for a User and Password, I don't see these in nifi-app.log.

Is there a default User/Password?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 1):

if you are on linux just run this command to set custom user/password for single user nifi:

```sh
cd <nifi_root_folder>
./bin/nifi.sh set-single-user-credentials <username> <password>
```

for windows there is a workaround to set custom credentials:

```sh
cd <nifi_root_folder>
java -cp conf;lib\bootstrap\* -Dnifi.properties.file.path=conf/nifi.properties ^
  org.apache.nifi.authentication.single.user.command.SetSingleUserCredentials ^
  <username> <password>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you start a plain new nifi instance you will find the username and password in `logs/nifi-app.log`.
somewhere should be printed a line like this:

```
Generated Username [ae7b6dd8-bc89-44b0-a025-abe1230e6327]
Generated Password [DPwOASAEiXKHKAtR6CuzfNrRIVH+iU4o]
```